# Unidentified "Launching Application" window on startup

Tags: windows-7, boot

This question pertains to Windows 7.

I'm not sure what has changed in my configuration, but now I have a window that pops up momentarily during my boot sequence that says "Launching Application", with a progress indicator.

This disturbs me because, well, I don't know what it's launching!

Has anyone else encountered this window, and if so, to what application / process does it belong?

If not, what is the best way to find out what application this dialog is connected to?

Comment: What operating system? if possible to show a print.

Comment: @TiagoCA - check tags: Windows-7

Comment: @TomAuger - Tags are easy to miss.  Its a good idea to mention the operating system.  A screenshot would also be nice.  If you wonder the reason for the downvote the lack of information is the reason, address those reasons, and I will serve an up vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to see a comprehensive overview of auto-starting locations on your computer, take a look at [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) which is part of the Windows Sysinternals Suite. I'm reasonably sure there is no way to impose a specific startup order on the various entries without invoking third-party tools for **some** of the locations listed in Autoruns.

One of the creators of the program has also published [an article](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server/autoruns) explaining the tool more thoroughly than the Sysinternals site does. It's from 2004 but most of it still applies.

Don't forget to create a backup before meddling with some of the more exotic tabs in the program!

Comment: Looks promising. If possible, please include a link to the article you mention. Also, I should point out that I'm not interested in playing with the startup order! Just in finding out what is running and when it hits so I would have been able to determine what process is behind the window that was popping up.

Comment: @Tom Done. Just forgot to add that link.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this window is associated with the "Dell System Detect" application, which was installed automatically through the Dell Support website as part of their online diagnostic tool. Kind of bogus that it runs on startup all the time. Uninstalling the application removed the startup window as well.

Having said that, I'll still happily accept another answer that outlines some good ways to monitor your startup processes.

The only way I know is to use the System Configuration control panel item and selectively disable startup processes. This would work in a case such as mine because the startup process had a visible effect (namely that annoying window I wanted to get rid of).

But it would be cool to know if there were some other diagnostic tools that let you see sort of a timeline of your boot sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Along With the dell system detect is a dell system detect bootstrapper. Uninstalling the bootstrapper stops the panel from appearing.